# How to wrap a container to have a background gradient using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I wrap a class container so I can have a 100% background gradient? I don't want it applied to the complete body though. Just to the container.

Answer (score 0):

add a class to the container div element For eg 
`<div class ="container wrapclr">
 Some content here
</div>`

In Css file include 
`.wrapclr
{
background-gradient:your choice;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean you want the container to be 100% of the screen or not, but assuming so,  you need to set the html and body to 100% height, put a 100% height container within that, and either add the gradient to the container, or add a second class alongside it.

CSS

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
}

.container{
  height:100%;
}

.gradient {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.0)));
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container gradient">Container with a gradient</div>
...
```

Here it is in action: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qluAb)

You could also just add the css within .gradient directly to the container, but this way you can add a gradient to any element by adding the .gradient class to it.